# What about an approximation of the Hölder's constant associated to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\gamma^n\cos(11^n\pi x)$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler's constant?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, continuity, holder-spaces

With $a=\gamma$ the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $b=11$ I've created this Weierstrass function, see [this Wikipedia if your need it,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)
$$W(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\gamma^n\cos(11^n\pi x).\tag{1}$$

I was exploring this definition proving claims like that (using uniform convergence) $$\int_0^{1/2}W(x)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+\gamma}.$$
After I wondered about an independet question: since our function is Hölder continuous I'm curious to know what about the associated constant $C$.

> **Question.** What about an estimation of our constant $C$? I am asking what can we say about the size of this constant $C$. **Many thanks.**

I can not say anything about the size of this constant $C$, for our function with the corresponding associated exponent. Is it possible deduce a lower and/or an upper bound for $C$?

Comment: I add here this cod  for Wolfram Alpha online calculator, if you want to see the graph of a truncated sum of our series: `plot sum gamma^n cos(11^n pi x), from n=0 to 300, for 0<x<10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=-\log\gamma/\log b$. Then $\gamma=b^{-a}$and $0<a<1$. We have
$$
|\cos(b^n\,\pi\,x)-\cos(b^n\,\pi\,y)|\le\min(2,b^n\,\pi\,|x-y|).
$$
Let $N$ be the largest integer such that $b^N\,\pi\,|x-y|\le2$. Then
\begin{align}
|W(x)-W(y)|&\le\sum_{n=0}^Nb^{-na}\,b^n\,\pi\,|x-y|+2\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty b^{-na}\\
&=\frac{\pi\,b^{1-a}\bigl(b^N|x-y|\bigr)^{1-a}}{b^{1-a}-1}|x-y|^a+2\,\frac{b^{-(N+1)a}}{b^{1-a}-1}\\
&\le\frac{\pi\,b^{1-a}(2/\pi)^{1-a}}{b^{1-a}-1}|x-y|^a+\frac{2\,(2/\pi)^{1-a}}{b^{1-a}-1}|x-y|^a.
\end{align}
Thus
$$
C\le\frac{(2/\pi)^{1-a}}{b^{1-a}-1}(\pi\,b^{1-a}+2).
$$

Comment: Many thanks now and tomorrow I am going to study your great answer. Many thanks for your attention and answers in this site.